# Pustules in ears and eyes of an abandoned rabbit (appearance and dissapearance)

Tags: rabbits, veterinarian, ticks

[image]
[image]
He/she recently appeared in the bush of a semi-rural place in Spain. It has been 15 days since my first encounter. He/she was very vivid and did not escape from people. 10 days later, I discovered that there were some pustules in the eyelids and ears. The bunny seemed to be suffering. (Maybe it's also due to the warm weather). I tried to capture him/her but it was really difficult.

[image]
Tick-free 5 days later... Not sure if someone went to help or it's just nature.

Since the situation keeps on changing, I have updated my question and here it is:
Given that local rescue organizations are not quite responsive and the bunny seems enjoying the wildlife, I don't know if I should just keep an eye on him/her or there is some more proactive method. 
(e.g. maybe there is some antiparasite/disinfection medicine that can be mixed with feed. Recommendations, please. What I am doing right now is holding a disinfection spray and chasing the bunny...)

Comment: Related [How do you tell a wild rabbit from a release domestic rabbit in southwestern Europe?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/20696/how-do-you-tell-a-wild-rabbit-from-a-release-domestic-rabbit-in-southwestern-eur)

Comment: Poor little bunny. Thank God you care. If you keep feeding it, it will likely get closer to you and be able to be caught.

Comment: After several searches about rabbit breeds, I think he/she is a tan rabbit. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tan_rabbit

Comment: @luw let us know how you get on with him/her. You can also pop into our chat room with updates https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/10964/the-litter-box

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a domestic rabbit, it was someone's pet it, has been released in the wild to die a long painful death. Even in areas where the [European rabbit are native, if it looks domestic, it is a released pet.](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/20696/how-do-you-tell-a-wild-rabbit-from-a-release-domestic-rabbit-in-southwestern-eur)

The 'pustules' are difficult to see clearly in the image, but the one on the ear may be a tick.  The rabbit needs urgent medical attention, if you can take them to a vet today that would be great!  Alternately contact a local animal shelter or rabbit rescue.

Not all animal shelters take domestic rabbits, if yours doesn't, or if they will not come out and pick it up.  Check https://rabbit.org/ for your nearest rabbit rescue, not every rabbit rescue is listed at rabbit.org if the nearest listed is far away from you, contact them for info about one closer to you.

Related posts

- [How to kill ticks on a Rabbit?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/17584/how-to-kill-ticks-on-a-rabbit)
- [Can I release my pet rabbit in the wild?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/1578/can-i-release-my-pet-rabbit-in-the-wild)
- [Are rabbits really the third most popular pet?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/1214/are-rabbits-really-the-third-most-popular-pet)
- [What should I know before I decide to adopt a rabbit?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/1240/what-should-i-know-before-i-decide-to-adopt-a-rabbit)
- [How do I get rid of fleas on my rabbit?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/925/how-do-i-get-rid-of-fleas-on-my-rabbit)
- [Can wild cottontail rabbits interbreed with domestic rabbits?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/13581/can-wild-cottontail-rabbits-interbreed-with-domestic-rabbits/20655#20655)
- [One of my three pet bunnies jumped out of the hutch and we can't catch her](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/7252/one-of-my-three-pet-bunnies-jumped-out-of-the-hutch-and-we-cant-catch-her)

**Updates after edits and other posts by OP.**

From your description of interacting with the bunny, it lets you get close enough to spray meds on it's ears, but is not ready for you touch it yet. There are a couple of references above with help for catching a skittish pet bunny.

The longer he/she stays free the more likely he/she will die. [A loose pet rabbit is not 'Free' it is 'Food'.](https://rabbit.org/easter/flyer/food-not-free.pdf) Unlike Cats, domestic rabbits do not have long periods getting over being feral, they re-domesticate very quickly. If it is truly a released pet then the sooner you can capture it the better.

Rabbits are very territorial. It is likely it will stay in the same general area.  They will be more active during the early morning and late evening (Dawn and Dusk).  I am guessing from the photos that the rabbit is near a walking path.  I suggest using a live animal trap as pictured below, you have been feeding treats for a couple of days now.  Start putting the treats in the trap, in the same place.  These traps can often be borrowed from local rescues, or purchased relatively cheaply.  It is best if you can stay in the area of the trap while waiting for the bunny. If you don't catch it in the morning leave the treats, take the trap and come back in the evening to try again.

[image: Live animal trap]

Comment: I am in Spain but thanks to your tip, I managed to find a local rabbit protection group. As he/she doesn't show up frequently, I am thinking of bringing carrots and water there to make him/her appear first. I should also get a cage.

Comment: @luw glad to hear that you are working towards a happy solution.  I add [another related link](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/7252/one-of-my-three-pet-bunnies-jumped-out-of-the-hutch-and-we-cant-catch-her) to my answer, it should provide some info to help you catch the bunny.

Comment: @luw feed carrots in moderation see related [Are carrots a healthy part of a rabbit diet?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/a/1833/13)

Comment: I see. The basic feed is the grass in the bush, which should be abundant. I will bring one carrot every 2 days. For the ticks and the purulent things around the eyelids, I contacted veterinarians and local rabbit rescue organizations but they couldn't help me with the capture. I tried with my friends but without success... However, today I found him/her tick-free and very energetic. I used some disinfection spray over the ears as the wounds from tick bite were still visible. He/she first tried to escape but later calmed down. Maybe it's better to be like this, living in the semi-wildness.

Comment: 3 days ago, I reached out to individuals working in exotic animals protection who are willing to help. It took us almost one hour this morning for a peaceful capture. The bunny was first angry but soon calmed down. Immediately, the bunny (a girl less than 1-year-old) has been taken to the vet by the great volunteers. The ticks were growing back on her and her "rural house" won't be sustainable in a Spanish summer but she is now saved from all these. I'm amazingly recharged as well not only from the knowledge I gained here but also all the kind encouragement I received. Thank you, pets.se!